# ng-if with animated class doesn't work with ng-mouseover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animate.css

I have a link that when I'm over it I change a variable value, so a `<p>` tag will be shown with ng-if. The code is as follow:

```
<div class="position text-center" ng-mouseover="social=1" ng-mouseleave="social=-1">
        <a   href="#6thPage">something</a>
    </div>
```

And the ng-if part is as follows

```
<div class="col-md-12 center-block text-center grey" ng-if="social == 1">
<p class="fadeInDown animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates quibusdam ullam tenetur facilis cupiditate iusto laudantium, ex nobis.</p>
</div>
```

When I remove the fadeInDown and animated class it works properly. But when I use it as above there is a little flicker when I move my mouse over the link.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using `ng-if`. I solved it using `ng-class` instead. For your problem, I would suggest the following solution:

1. Keep your div, of whose visibility you want to toggle, to `display: none` by default:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 center-block text-center grey hide-element">
<p class="fadeInDown animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates quibusdam ullam tenetur facilis cupiditate iusto laudantium, ex nobis.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide-element {
    display: none;
}
```

2. The create a class which you add to the div when 'social == 1':

**CSS:**

```
.show-element{
    display: block;
}
```

3. Now, add an `ng-class` for toggling visibility using the 'show-element' class:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 center-block text-center grey" ng-class="{'show-element': social  == 1, 'hide-element': social != 1}">
<p class="fadeInDown animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates quibusdam ullam tenetur facilis cupiditate iusto laudantium, ex nobis.</p>
</div>
```

Also, I am assuming you are using animate.css?

Comment: Is there anything better than animate.css? I'm kind of new to these stuff.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes I just tried it And there is a problem. With ng-class the show-element added in the class list, but the hide-element also remains. How can I remove the hide-element?

Comment: The hide elements class adds and removes repeatedly. The problem still exists

Comment: I realized the problem happens with certain animation types. Like there is not any problem with fadeIn or bounceIn but the problem is with fadeInDown for example.

Comment: What exactly was the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I move mouse over the link the paragraph appears and disappears over and over.